# Google Maps click event does not work on mobile devices

Tags: google-maps-api, angularjs

I created a map using Google Maps API with Angular Material libraries (https://material.angularjs.org/)

After I upgraded Angular Material from 0.70 to 0.82, I found the info window did not show up by clicking the map on mobile phones or tablets.It looks like the map click event cannot be fired on touch screens. This issue did not happen when using the version 0.70.

The old map w/ Angular Material 0.70: 
http://csj-councildistricts.appspot.com/index.html

The new map w/ Angular Material 0.82: 
http://6.csj-councildistricts.appspot.com/index.html

Does anyone have the similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

you could disable click hijacking by configure the `$mdGestureProvider`
specially used with the project that use jQuery with angular material

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
      .config(function( $mdGestureProvider ) {
          $mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();
     });
```

check this [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1441) on angular material github.